# How to determine Pig Execution Mode programatically

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

How can we determine whether pig is running in Local Mode or Map Reduce Mode ? Are there any specific commands to find it out ?

Comment: Why do you need to know?

Comment: @WinnieNicklaus It is a programming requirement...

Answer (score 0):

Why you need this?

`-x local` and `pig` or `-x mapreduce` is the commandline option for 2 modes.

And programatically we do

```
PigServer pigServer = new PigServer("local");

PigServer pigServer = new PigServer("mapreduce");
```

I think we can **log** it.

There may be better practices.

Answer (score 0):

If you're invoking Pig programatically, but for some reason don't know the run mode that was chosen when Pig was started, you could call getPigContext().getExecType() on the PigServer instance.

If you need to know the run mode within a Pig script, you could access the client-side command line arguments and parse the run mode from within a UDF as follows:

```
UDFContext context = UDFContext.getUDFContext();
Properties props = context.getClientSystemProps();
String commandArgs = props.getProperty("pig.cmd.args");
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("-x\\s+local");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(commandArgs);
boolean isLocal = matcher.find();
```